# Obtain user id of accounts retweeting a tweet - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am using ruby and the Twitter API and i was wondering if it was possible to obtain the user id's of the people who have retweeted a tweet. I have the tweet id so the i imagine the command would look something like this

```
retweeters = tweet(tweet_id).get_retweeters
```

Where retweeters is a collection of user id's

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter gem documentation doesn't include anything method for getting retweeters, but you could alternatively send an AJAX request to get up to 100 retweeters using a GET request like this:

```
GET statuses/retweeters/ids
```

You can find the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids